# Create jQuery object from a string containing parentheses is throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im stuck with jQuery 1.7.2 (cannot upgrade it since it's a client's choice).

This is my scenario: I have a js variable (written by client) and I need to examine it in order to see if it contains javascript and if yes, execute it (just imagine there are no security risks).
This is my simple implementation:

```
$(value).filter("script").each(function () {
        let scriptFn = new Function(this.text);
        scriptFn();
    });
```

Problem is that when the value contains some special characters (for example value="a(b)", then $(value) is throwing an exception:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (b)

Can anyone explain me why I cannot create a jQuery object with a string containing parenthesis? Is it some king of a forbidden character? Any workarounds?

thank you

Comment: I know you said to ignore the potential security risks but I do want to say that even if you are pretty sure there are none somebody could introduce some later. It is very important to make safe code a habit. Beyond that I think it would be better to use `eval` than `new Function(string)` because `eval` is more easily recognized. That way other developers know immediately what is happening.

Comment: `$()` expects either a valid selector, a DOM Element, or html markup that it will convert into DOM Elements.  `a(b)` is not valid for any of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

**"a(b)"** is a function call. The value that you have passed is to be the selector argument of the jquery. For the selectors jquery have only certain predefined functions like *eq(2)*, *nth-child(2)*, and similar. Since the jquery does not have this method a(b) defined within it is throwing the unrecognized expression error.

Answer (score 0):

You would be to write a selector that would accept escaped arguments, for example:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    containsEscaped: function (el, index, m) {  
        var s = unescape(m[3]);
        return $(el).text().indexOf(s) >= 0;
    }  
});
```

Refer my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/9wWP5/15/

Answer (score 0):

as Amuthesan explained, jQuery cannot accept anything as a selector. 
So workaround for me is not to use jQuery :)

```
let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = value;
    let scripts = tmp.getElementsByTagName("script");
    Array.from(scripts).forEach(function (script) {
        let scriptFn = new Function(script.text);
        scriptFn();
    });
```